# Is my analysis of the grammatical structure of this sentence correct?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> If you want something in your life you’ve never had, you’ll have to do something you’ve never done.

- Dependent clause

  - *You* — subject
  - *want* — main verb
  - *something* — direct object, assertive pronoun
  - *in* — preposition
  - *your* — possessive pronoun
  - *life* — noun, direct object
- Relative clause

  - *that* (elided) — relative pronoun
  - *you* — noun
  - *have never* (adverb) *had* — present perfective
- Independent clause

  - *you* — subject
  - *will have* — main verb
  - *to do* — infinitive
  - *something* — direct object, assertive pronoun
- Relative clause

  - *that* (elided) — relative pronoun
  - *you* — noun
  - *have never* (adverb) *done* — present perfective

Comment: Looks reasonable to me, but I'm no expert on the [naming of parts](http://www.solearabiantree.net/namingofparts/namingofparts.html), and there are too many here for me to check out each one. Is there anything in particular you're unsure about?

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis looks correct. Here are some more points you can include:

```
If you want something in your life you’ve never had - conditional sentence
If - conjunction
```

You can also include the tenses on your main verbs like you did in your relative clauses:

```
want - simple present
will - auxiliary verb expressing futurity
have - simple present
```

Assertive pronouns also fall under a bigger umbrella of indefinite pronouns: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_pronoun

The whole sentence is a "complex sentence".

Comment: Just to be clear, English has no future tense, but has several ways of expressing the future, of which *will* + plain form of the verb is just one.

Comment: I invite you to consider whether "have to do" should be parsed as [*have* (auxiliary) + *to do* (marked infinitive)] or [*have to* (phrasal modal) + *do* (unmarked infinitive)].